# Power Tile Combo: Initiative combined with Crusade

Tags: kemet

When using the Initiative power tile (which destroys two units pre-battle) combined with the Crusade power tile (which gives Ankhs per units destroyed in battle):

Does the attacking player get ankhs for the units destroyed 'pre battle'?
If the is no battle because the defender had two units or less, does the attacker get any Ankhs?

The mystery here is that the escape DI card cancels a battle, but also works for initiative, which seems to indicate that units killed by initiative are in some sort of odd edge-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said in the question, Crusade gives you ☥ for units killed in Battle.

As you also stated correctly, the effects of the Initiative happen before the Battle. (The power tile itself shows that it's a day phrase tile, not a battle phrase tile.) Therefore the kills of the Initiative won't generate ☥.

And there is no mystery with the Escape DI card: it cancels the Battle. Therefore effects before the battle phrase can't happen. Therefore the Initiative tile won't have effects.